# Vim mapping with user input

Tags: vim

I'm wondering if it's possible in Vim to create a mapping (for normal mode) that allows user input before the mapping executes.

I want to create a mapping for a shortcut for my most used grep command. I want the command to allow to to enter what I'm searching for then execute on enter.

This is sort of what I want:

```
nmap F :grep! "*user input*"<CR>:cw<CR>
```

I can't figure out how to pause and take user input. Am I even thinking about this the right way? Are there better ways to do what I'm trying to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An alternative would be create a custom command and use a mapping to call the new command.

```
command! -nargs=+ -complete=file -bar Grep grep! <args>|cw
```

Now you can create your mapping:

```
nnoremap <f2> :Grep<space>
```

You probably also want to stay away from mapping the `F` key as it a pretty handy mapping.

For more help see:

```
:h :command
```

Comment: Good answer. I would map it as `nnoremap <f2> :Grep<space>` so that it is easier to know the space is there in your vimrc.

Answer (score 17):

There is a function `input(prompt [, text [, completion]])`:

> The result is a String, which is whatever the user typed on the
>   command-line.  The {prompt} argument is either a prompt string, or a
>   blank string (for no prompt).  A '\n' can be used in the prompt to
>   start a new line.

(from `:help input()`).

For things like `:grep!`, you'll probably have to build the command using a string expression and then `:execute` it.

Comment: Could you point me to an example of what you mean by "build the command using a string expression"? Thanks!

Comment: Something like `:exec ":grep! ".input("grep what? where?")`

Answer (score 0):

see also [this answer on vi.stackexchange by @EvergreenTree](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6030/2239)

in short: map an expression to make use of `input()`:

`nnoremap <expr> ;n "<ESC>Go<CR>" . input("Input your text here: ", "Prepend this string to my input by default -") . " <<- that was your input.<ESC>"`