# Can you use vimscript to enter and exit command mode?

Tags: vim

I recently learned that `cnoremap` maps keys/chords in vim's command mode, similar to how `inoremap` and `nnoremap` work in insert and normal mode, respectively.  Interestingly, mappings created this way apply not only when using `:`, but also when using `/` or `?`.  This made me realize that it's quite likely vimscript can take advantage of command mode the way these normal mode commands do.  Assuming it is possible, what I'd like to know is this:

> How do you enter command mode, wait for user input, and then act upon that input after the user presses enter?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the only working way to search Stack Overflow is to write an entire question out and look at the "Similar questions" section.  Both [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388703/vim-mapping-with-user-input) and [this other question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6029/how-to-wait-for-user-input-in-the-middle-of-a-mapping/6030#6030) have references to the `input()` function, which does in fact put the user in the command mode, and can, as far as I can tell, be used along with other vimscripting functions to reproduce the exact behavior of `/`, `?`, and `:`.